# Oracle12 sdo_nn fails to return the shortest distance object

Tags: sql, oracle, geolocation

I have a table of `NODES` and a table of `RESTAURANTS` with their `GEOLOC` and coordinates.

```
select n.geoloc.sdo_point.y as node_y, n.geoloc.sdo_point.x as node_x,
r.state as r_state, r.geoloc.sdo_point.y as r_y, r.geoloc.sdo_point.x as r_x,
sdo_nn_distance(1)  as distance_mi
from   DC_NODE n,  RESTAURANTS r
where   sdo_nn (n.geoloc, r.geoloc, 'Unit = MILE sdo_num_res = 1',1) ='TRUE'

NODE_Y NODE_X   R_state  R_Y   R_X   distance_mi
38.      -77.       AK   56.  -132.  2752.
```

Here `sdo_nn_distance(1)` and `where   sdo_nn(...)` should constrain the results set to a set of nodes and corresponding closest restaurants. The shortest distance clause seem to be ignored by Oracle.

I do have entries much closer to the node:

```
    --DC Restaurants are in the table
    select r.STATE, r.geoloc.sdo_point.y as r_y, r.geoloc.sdo_point.x as r_x
      from RESTAURANTS rwhere r.state = 'DC'

    DC  38. -77.
    DC  38. -76.
    DC  38. -77.
```

Why is Oracle ignoring the "find the nearest" clause and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Changed the sequence of args to fix the problem
`sdo_nn (from_these_objects_to_choose.geoloc, for_each_of_these_objects.geoloc, 'Unit = MILE sdo_num_res = 1',1) ='TRUE'`